# RS-232 проброс в локальной сети

Tags: linux, передача-данных

Всем привет. Как реализовать решение  на картинке. На первом PC работает SER2NET. Нужно  настроить SOCAT на втором PC, чтобы получился виртуальный кабель в локальной сети.
[image: ser2net -- LAN ----LAN ----socat]

Comment: Ответ вроде выглядит тривиальным, что значит, что вы его скорее всего пробовали, и оно у вас не заработало. Расскажите, что делали, и как были настроены socat и ser2net в ваших попытках.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Действительно, я не могу отправить из socat  в существующий  порт на Linux_PC2.

Comment: ser2net.conf на Linux_PC1 :  1884:raw:0:/dev/ttyS0:19200 NONE 2STOPBITS 8DATABITS -XONXOFF -RTSCTS LOCAL

Comment: socat на Linux_PC2:  sudo  socat PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVUSB0  tcp:Linux_PC1:1884    отправляет данные в виртуальный порт ttyVUSB0 и я читаю и отправляю  данные. Как отправить в существующий физический порт? Простая замена на /dev/ttyS0 не работает.

Comment: почему pty? адаптер же не терминал

Comment: socat мощный и я просто уже запутался.

Comment: Попробуйте ком-порт открывать через GOPEN, устанавливая скорость: GOPEN:/dev/ttyS0,b19200,raw,echo=0. Убедитесь предварительно, что порты между Linux_PC2 и windows вообще правильно соединены, то есть что вы вообще каким-либо методом (minicom, putty) можете добиться прохождения байтов между этими двумя машинами, используя на линуксе ttyS0. Потом переходите к strace, чтобы посмотреть, что́ вообще socat читает-пишет. И да, 2 стоп-бита — это несколько необычно.

Answer (score 0):

Для первого ПЦ вот такую штуку делал на питоне.

```
import asyncio
import serial_asyncio
import sys


class Output(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        self.tcp = None
        print('port opened', transport)
        transport.serial.rts = False  # You can manipulate Serial object via transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('data received', repr(data))
        if self.tcp:
            self.tcp.write(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('port closed')
        sys.exit(1)

    def pause_writing(self):
        print('pause writing')
        print(self.transport.get_write_buffer_size())

    def resume_writing(self):
        print(self.transport.get_write_buffer_size())
        print('resume writing')

    def set_tcp(self, transport):
        self.tcp = transport


class ProxyServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, serial):
        self.serial = serial

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport
        self.serial.set_tcp(transport)

    def data_received(self, data):
        self.serial.transport.write(data)


async def main(loop):
    serial_transpot, serial_protocol = await serial_asyncio.create_serial_connection(loop, Output, sys.argv[1], baudrate=115200)
    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: ProxyServerProtocol(serial_protocol),
        '0.0.0.0', 5555)
    await server.wait_closed()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Сокат плохо ведет себя в реконнекте. Но вот так запускается и стабильно при стабильном эзернете.

```
PORT=$(readlink -f $1)

echo $PORT

while true; do
    socat TCP-LISTEN:5555 $PORT,b115200,raw,echo=0 || sleep 1;
done;
```

Для второго ПЦ (тоже обернуть в while true)

```
socat TCP:192.168.0.1:5555 $PORT,b115200,raw,echo=0 || sleep 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.